# phpspec not finding my specs with a configuration file and in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpspec

phpspec isn't finding any of my specs while using a config file and PhpStorm can't find my specs no matter what I do.

I'm loading my classes with psr-4, and `dump-autoload -o` does indeed find the class that I want to test.

```
'Plexus\\oAuth2Server\\User\\Authenticate' => $baseDir . '/src/User/Authenticate.php',
```

In my composer, and I think this could have something to do with the two-namespace prefix,

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Plexus\\oAuth2Server\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

So, I think that part's not the problem.

Without the config file, when I run `./vendor/bin/phpspec run` my test does run and pass, but I can't get it working in PhpStorm.  I've tried setting the test scope to the project directory, to the spec directory.  I've tried setting the `Custom working directory` to both as well.  It doesn't want to find my specs.

So I decided I would try a config file.

```
suites:
    user_suite:
        namespace: Plexus\oAuth2Server
        psr4_prefix: Plexus\oAuth2Server
        spec_path: spec
        src_path: src
```

which results in:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpspec run main
/  skipped: 0%  /  pending: 0%  /  passed: 0%   /  failed: 0%   /  broken: 0%   /  0 examples
0 specs
0 examples
0ms
```

Comment: why `./vendor/bin/phpspec run main` ? run takes a spec directory as an argument. Can you try simply `./vendor/bin/phpspec run` ?

Comment: Turns out this is a bug.